# Delete latest DML action

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a trigger that prevents any users that is not me from doing DML injections, whoever tries get the error message "Sorry, you are not allowed to do this"

However my trigger shows this message, but still goes ahead with the code that the user sent. Is there any way to prevent this from happening, ignoring the statement, or deleting the most recent transaction?

Sidenote: I know, using a trigger for this is probably not the way to go, but please ignore this, I'm trying to learn, and right now I'm learning triggers.

Thank you

```
create or replace trigger my_ex
before insert or update or delete on kund
declare
my_ex exception;
begin
if user not in ('me') then raise my_ex;
end if;
exception
When only_boss then raise_application_error(-20009,'Illegal activity!');
rollback;
end;
/
```

Comment: Please show your code!  You need to raise an exception and have the caller deal with it by doing a rollback.

Comment: Please have a look now, rollback is not allowed

Comment: But you are doing a rollback.  The proper way to do this is not through triggers, but assigning rights with GRANTS to the table.  Non-"me" users would maybe have READ access only.

Comment: It seems like you are student of the very same class as the OP of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188002/exception-to-handle-unpermitted-dml-operation/29188292#29188292

Answer (score 0):

Your exception must be declared like this:

```
my_ex EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(my_ex, -20001);
```

Then user names in Oracle are capital by default, i.e. you should write

```
if user not in ('ME') then 
   raise my_ex;
end if;
```

Comment: PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT is not necessary in this case. It is used when you want to catch ORA-20001 which has been raised in some other block of code (and since >20000 stands for user defined exceptions, it is bit overcomplicated to catch my own exception instead of handling it where it raises), so it is useful for existing ORA exception codes.